# Usage du mot "fracas"

Tags: sens, usage

Le mot fracas est-il considéré vieux ? Peut-on l'utiliser couramment ? En anglais le mot fracas (emprunt au français) signifie bagarre (quarrel). Peut-on aussi l'utiliser avec le même sens en français ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En français, le mot "fracas" signifie littéralement "[bruit violent et soudain](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fracas/34925?q=fracas#34889)" ou "agitation bruyante". Dans le cas d'une bagarre, on peut considérer que c'est un emploi correct puisque décrivant un moment d'agitation bruyante.

C'est un mot que tout le monde comprend, mais en tant que natif dans la vingtaine, issu d'un milieu "moyen", je ne l'emploierais pas naturellement, en tout cas à l'oral.

On peut également citer l'expression "[avec pertes et fracas](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avec_pertes_et_fracas)", qui se rencontre régulièrement lorsque quelqu'un raconte un départ brutal (par exemple lorsqu'un article de presse relate la démission agitée d'un homme politique), et qui [tend à être de plus en plus utilisée](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pertes%20et%20fracas&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpertes%20et%20fracas%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpertes%20et%20fracas%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

[Fracas (dictionnaire de l'Académie)](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F1473) indique plusieurs sens mais aucun qui signifie *bagarre*.

Ce n'est pas d'un usage très courant dans la langue parlée.